# Full (responsive) width of a div with background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to have the blue div to be the full width of a page for every device. I'm using bootstrap 3.0 and I also tried to end the background div immediately. I don't like using a custom width because that will be annoying for making it responsive.

[screenshot how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI2HQ.png)

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U23NG.png)

```css
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.background {
    background-color: #24a5e8;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.gratis_text{
    font-family: Segoe UI Symbol;
    color: black;

}
#gratis_h2 {
    margin-left: 24%;
}
#hr1 {
    border-color: black;
    margin-left: 24%;
    width: 39%;
}
#span1-1 {
    margin-left: 23%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"> <!-- background -->
                    <div class="row"> <!-- row -->
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
                            <div class="gratis_text">
                                <h2 id="gratis_h2">Gratis pakket</h2>
                                <hr id="hr1">
                                <span id="span1-1">Geen addertjes onder het gras! </span> <br>
                                <span>U kunt als bedrijf zich altijd GRATIS aanmelden zonder verplichtingen!</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- /row -->
                </div> <!-- /background -->
```

Comment: It's already working fine, though it is not the same output in the screenshot you provided. can you please explain further what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The code works as intended in a fiddle, you mostly have other elements in the page which are causing the issues with the width. You can try adding `margin: 0;` to the `html, body` elements of the page

Comment: Maybe bootstrap is causing the problem? But I don't know I'm new to bootstrap